# Creating protruding button from tab bar on iOS

Tags: iphone

I've seen a couple of apps that have 1 button in what looks like a UITabBar protruding outside the frame.

How does one go about doing something like this? Code samples/tutorial suggestions to read would be much appreciated.

Here's a photo from one the apps I've seen this in.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/) explains exactly what you need